# Generate all 3-permutations of the set {x, y, z, w, u, t} excluding the ones where 'u' is after 't'

Tags: pattern-matching

I have to generate all 3-permutations of a the set $(x, y, z, w, u, t)$ without the ones where the element $u$ is after element $t$.

So far I have generated all the the 3-permutations like such

```
set = {x, y, z, w, u, t};
Permutations[set, {3, 3}];
```

but I can't figure a way to exclude the ones that satisfy the given condition.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `DeleteCases[Permutations[set, {3, 3}], {___, t, ___, u, ___}]`...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is via pattern matching and [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html):

```
set = {x, y, z, w, u, t};

DeleteCases[Permutations[set, {3}], {___, t, ___, u, ___}]
```

I've omitted the output because it's 108 terms. Also, note that

```
Permutations[set, {3}] === Permutations[set, {3, 3}]
```

by definition.

Comment: Left side of the equality gives the permutations, from the given set, with 0, 1, and 2 elements also.

Comment: I forgot to thank you, Pillsy.

Comment: @user242760 No it doesn't, if you use the curly braces. Pillsy is correct. You are thinking of `Permutations[set, 3]` instead, which gives the permutations containing *at most* 3 elements.